# How to split one text file line into different lines for output c program

Tags: c, text-files, txt

I have a text file that contains order data of people that purchase few items, they are stored in one single line in text file. How do I print out a text file content that is in a single line but I want the output to be printed in different lines?

Example:
Text file content:

wana    DR02    Iced    Americano   8.90    SW03    Beef    Bacon   6.50    SK01    HotnSpicy   Chips   5.00

Output:

- wana
- DR02 Iced    Americano   8.90
- SW03 Beef    Bacon   6.50
- SK01 HotnSpicy   Chips   5.00

```
void AddOdr()
{
    FILE *drk;
    FILE *sdwh;
    FILE *cke;
    FILE *snck;
    FILE *odr;
    FILE *tmp;
    int p;
    char username[50];
    char code[50];
    char fname[50];
    char lname [50];
    float price;
    float total = 0;
    float amt;
    float bal;
    int quantity;
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    int y;
    int menu;
    char t;
    tmp = fopen ("temp.txt","w");
    printf("\n\nEnter your username for account verification: ");
    scanf("%s", &username);
    fprintf(tmp,"%s\t",username);
    drk = fopen("drink.txt","r");
    sdwh = fopen("sandwich.txt","r");
    cke = fopen("cake.txt","r");
    snck = fopen("snack.txt","r");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\tDISCLAIMER TO ALL CUSTOMERS!\nYOU CAN PURCHASE ONLY ONE ITEM FROM EACH CATEGORY PER ORDER\n(MAX 4 ITEMS PER ORDER)\n");
    printf("\nHow many items would you like to buy?\n\n:");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    while (i<=j)
    {
        printf("\n\nWhich category would you like to buy?\n1.Drinks\n2.Sandwiches\n3.Cake and Pastries\n4.Snacks\n\n:");
        scanf("%d", &p);
        switch (p){
            case 1: printf("\nEnter the code you want to purchase: ");
                    scanf("%s",&code);
                    while (fscanf (drk, "%s %s %s %f\n",&prc.code,&prc.fname,&prc.lname,&prc.price) != EOF){
                        if (strcmp(code,prc.code) == 0){
                        printf ("%s", code);
                        printf ("\n%.2f", prc.price);
                        fprintf (tmp, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2f\t",prc.code,prc.fname,prc.lname,prc.price);
                        total += prc.price;

                        }
                    }
            break;
            case 2: printf("\nEnter the code you want to purchase: ");
                    scanf("%s",&code);
                    while (fscanf (sdwh, "%s %s %s %f\n",&prc.code,&prc.fname,&prc.lname,&prc.price) != EOF){
                        if (strcmp(code,prc.code) == 0){
                        printf ("%s", code);
                        printf ("\n%.2f", prc.price);
                        fprintf (tmp, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2f\t",prc.code,prc.fname,prc.lname,prc.price);
                        total += prc.price;
                        }
                    }
            break;
            case 3: printf("\nEnter the code you want to purchase: ");
                    scanf("%s",&code);
                    while (fscanf (cke, "%s %s %s %f\n",&prc.code,&prc.fname,&prc.lname,&prc.price) != EOF){
                        if (strcmp(code,prc.code) == 0){
                        printf ("%s", code);
                        printf ("\n%.2f", prc.price);
                        fprintf (tmp, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2f\t",prc.code,prc.fname,prc.lname,prc.price);
                        total += prc.price;
                        }
                    }
            break;
            case 4: printf("\nEnter the code you want to purchase: ");
                    scanf("%s",&code);
                    while (fscanf (snck, "%s %s %s %f\n",&prc.code,&prc.fname,&prc.lname,&prc.price) != EOF){
                        if (strcmp(code,prc.code) == 0){
                        printf ("%s", code);
                        printf ("\n%.2f", prc.price);
                        fprintf (tmp, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2f\t",prc.code,prc.fname,prc.lname,prc.price);
                        total += prc.price;
                        }
                    }
            break;

        }
        i++;
    }
    fprintf(tmp,"%.2f\n",total);
    fclose(tmp);
    printf ("\n\nTotal price is RM%.2f", total);
    printf("\nProceed with payment? \n\n1.Yes\n2.Cancel Order\n\n: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    switch (y){
        case 1: printf("Enter the amount you will be paying (RM): ");
                scanf("%f", &amt);
                bal = amt - total;

                if (total > amt){
                    printf("\nAmount entered is insufficient.\nPurchase attempt unsuccessful!\n");
                    printf ("...redirecting you back to Order Page...");
                    CustOdr();
                }
                else if (amt >= total){
                    printf("\nYour balance is RM%.2f",bal);
                    printf("\nThank you for purchasing from Dosta Coffee Shop!");
                    tmp = fopen ("temp.txt","r");
                    if (tmp == NULL){
                        printf("\n Unable to open file.\n");
                        quit();
                    }
                    odr = fopen("order.txt","a");
                    if (odr == NULL){
                        printf("\n Unable to open file.\n");
                        quit();
                    }
                    printf("\n\nYOUR ORDER:\n");
                    
                    while ((t = fgetc(tmp)) != EOF){
                        printf("%c",t); // need to print this in separate lines
                        fputc(t, odr);
                    }
                    fclose(odr);
                    fclose (tmp);
                    remove ("temp.txt");


                }
                else {
                    printf("Error occured!");
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Add a newline to the end of your `fprintf` format strings, instead of a tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fgets() function to read each line from the text file into a character array (buffer), then use the strtok() function to split the line into separate tokens. Finally, you can print each token on a separate line.

Here is a simple example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1024

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAX_LEN];
    char *token;

    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fp) != NULL) {

        // remove newline character from string
        line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;

        // split string into tokens using space as delimiter
        token = strtok(line, " ");

        // print each token on a separate line
        while (token != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```